# Cant create a user using Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4 and the following code suffers from a bug that i am not being able to find it :(
So i require your help.

One of the part of my code (that gives me the error) is shown here:

```
if($status == 'admin')
            {
                $role_id = 1;
            }
        else
            {
                $role_id = 2;
            }
        $check_role = DB::table('roles')->where('id', $role_id)->pluck('id');
        if(($password == $repeat_password)&&($check_role != 0)&&($first_name != "")&&($last_name != ""))
            {
                $user = User::create(array('username' => $username, 'password' => Hash::make($password), 'first_name'=>$first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name, 'no_total_leaves' => $no_total_leaves, 'active' => $active, 'role_id' => $role_id));
                return View::make('pages/manageUsers')->with('info', 'Success!');
            }
        else
            {
                return View::make('pages/manageUsers')->with('info','Failed!');

            }
```

I want to make you sure that roles table exists and it hase two rows (id =1 is admin, and is=2 is user).

The following error is shown:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`leaves_db`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `users_role_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `users` (`username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `no_total_leaves`, `active`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (demo .demo, y$BuTWHRpfPl.OztGhTltjteqvGZZ6xcbzlAnCgwrZYRxRDxB.fuqHe, demo , demo, 0, 1, 2015-01-12 11:35:55, 2015-01-12 11:35:55))
```

Comment: I did not said the role_id field is a foreign key on table roles->id. thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per above mentioned code, you are not inserting value of column role_id in table USERS.
  Bare in mind that **column role_id in table USERS is foreign key of column ID on table ROLES. So It should always be included in your every insert statement.**

```
 $user = User::create(array('username' => $username, 'password' => Hash::make($password), 'first_name'=>$first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name, 'no_total_leaves' => $no_total_leaves, 'active' => $active, 'role_id' => $role_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the query that is running is not actually inserting the role_id. I cannot see it in the query that the error shows.

Comment: as far as the role_id is a foreign key on the id field of the role table, i cannt add on my database table

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support. I needed to use this row instead:
DB::table('users')->insert(array('username' => $username, 'password' => Hash::make($password), 'first_name'=>$first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name, 'no_total_leaves' => $no_total_leaves, 'active' => $active, 'role_id' => $role_id));